# What am I doing wrong with this "If" statement?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

So, I have two if statements that detect if you're using the HTC 8X or 8S, going by the DeviceName supplied by the phone. The problem is that it seems to ignore the "If" and just run all of the code... for example, I placed a line of code (For debugging) that shows a messagebox once it runs each part, but both messageboxes were shown, instead of just the 8X one, showing it properly detected I was running the app on an 8X. This is probably just a "Stupid mistake", but I can't figure i out...

```
  if (Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName == "Windows Phone 8X by HTC") ;
            {
                //Debugging MSG
                MessageBox.Show("8X Works")
                //Rating
                MainScore.Text = "6.1";
                //Subscores
                Processor.Text = "5.2";
                RAM.Text = "6.5";
                Graphics.Text = "8.0";
                HardDisk.Text = "5.1";
                //Issues
                Issues.Text = "0 ISSUES FOUND";
            }
            if (Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName == "Windows Phone 8S by HTC");
            {
                //Debugging MSG
                MessageBox.Show("8S Works")
                //Rating
                MainScore.Text = "2.8";
                //Subscores
                Processor.Text = "3.2";
                RAM.Text = "2.4";
                Graphics.Text = "4.0";
                HardDisk.Text = "1.9";
                //Issues
                Issues.Text = "0 ISSUES FOUND";
            }
```

Answer (score 8):

Remove the semicolons immediately after each IF test.  The blocks of code after the semicolons just run unconditionally every time.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the semi-colons, here's how the compiler sees your code.
*(Look for the `/* */` comments)*

```
if (Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName == "Windows Phone 8X by HTC")
    /* DO NOTHING */;

/* Regular, Unconditional Code */
{
    //Debugging MSG
    MessageBox.Show("8X Works")
    //Rating
    MainScore.Text = "6.1";
    //Subscores
    Processor.Text = "5.2";
    RAM.Text = "6.5";
    Graphics.Text = "8.0";
    HardDisk.Text = "5.1";
    //Issues
    Issues.Text = "0 ISSUES FOUND";
}

if (Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName == "Windows Phone 8S by HTC")
    /* DO NOTHING */;

/* Regular Unconditional code */
{
   //Debugging MSG
   MessageBox.Show("8S Works")
   //Rating
   MainScore.Text = "2.8";
   //Subscores
   Processor.Text = "3.2";
   RAM.Text = "2.4";
   Graphics.Text = "4.0";
   HardDisk.Text = "1.9";
   //Issues
   Issues.Text = "0 ISSUES FOUND";
 }
```